# Trying to pass variable key into hvac write function

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Apologies for the dumb question, but I'd like to write variables to vault dynamically. I can't figure out the syntax for it. Maybe it's not possible. 
I'm basically trying to get this to work:

`vault_client.write('secret/foo/%s' path, '%s=%s' % (key, value))`.

When trying to run this, I get this error:
`strconv.ParseInt: parsing "key=value": invalid syntax`

hvac wants something like this:

`vault_client.write('secret/foo/path', key="value")`

Is there a way to do this in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary first. Pass the dictionary as the **kwargs to the function.

For example:

```
secrets = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'c': 'baz'}
path = 'secret/path'

client.write(path, **secrets)
```